# Copy file from sbt plugin to project folder

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm writing an sbt plugin to help with deployment.  It depends on sbt-native-packager.  Principally it adds a `deploy` task.  However, I also need it to copy a bash script `run-class.sh` into the `/bin` folder of the package.

How do I copy a file from the sbt plugin to my project?  Presently my only idea is to add the file to `src/main/resources/run-class.sh` in the plugin and [generate a file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html) using sbt.  Then I can supply a Universal mapping to put the file in the sbt-native-packager package.

Is there an easier way to get a file from the plugin into my sbt project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources), specifically [Generate resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources). You can keep your original file either as a resource or `String`, but important thing is that the files are generated into `resourceManaged in Compile`, which is under `target`. This folder is typically skipped from version control.

Comment: We ended up [doing something along those lines](https://github.com/allenai/sbt-plugins/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/allenai/plugins/VersionInjectorPlugin.scala#L116).

Comment: schmdd, thanks a lot, I wrote something very similar. But the question remains - how does the file get into the jar I build? In my case I have several project in Build.scala... (and of course the other question is how to make sure the file is generated every time...)